# WordPress sidebar with custom 'widget' select

Tags: php, wordpress, sidebar

I thought I was trying to create something pretty common, but I can't figure it out.

I want to be able to create / 'prepare' blocks of html, which you can assign to pages.

example:

- create a few content blocks (customer list, internal banner, maybe some fancy button)
- When editing / creating a new page, just 'check' which sidebar items you want to appear on that specific page

What would be even better if you were able to have multiple optional sidebars, i.e. left and right.

Is there any simple way to get this done?

Answer (score 2):

what you want can be achieved with [Widget Context](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/widget-context/) or [Shortcode Any Widget](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/amr-shortcode-any-widget/)